# Listar documentos con fecha mayor MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo la siguiente situación en mongo.
Tengo varios documentos que están repetidos, lo que está bien, sólo se se diferencian en la fecha de lectura de dichos documentos.
A continuación dejo un ejemplo de los documentos.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d840f71040e9c571c389d1b"),
    "marca" : "Toshiba",
    "titulo" : "ToshibaParlante BT Vintage Toshiba",
    "precio" : 109990,
    "fecha_lectura" : ISODate("2019-09-19T23:29:53.555Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d840c6ff949f51a80003b7e"),
    "marca" : "Toshiba",
    "titulo" : "ToshibaParlante BT Vintage Toshiba",
    "precio" : 109990,
    "fecha_lectura" : ISODate("2019-09-19T23:17:03.961Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d840f71040e9c571c389d20"),
    "marca" : "Toshiba",
    "titulo" : "ToshibaDisco Duro Externo Toshiba Canvio A3 2T",
    "precio" : 69990,
    "fecha_lectura" : ISODate("2019-09-19T23:29:53.560Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d840c6ff949f51a80003b80"),
    "marca" : "Toshiba",
    "titulo" : "ToshibaDisco Duro Externo Toshiba Canvio A3 2T",
    "precio" : 69990,
    "fecha_lectura" : ISODate("2019-09-19T23:17:03.979Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Y así con varios documentos que pueden estar repetidos por con diferente fecha de lectura.
Es posible listar sólo los documentos una única vez, que sería el de mayor fecha de lectura?, es decir, aunque un documento esté repetido "n" veces, sólo mostrar uno sólo.

Para el ejemplo sería:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d840f71040e9c571c389d1b"),
    "marca" : "Toshiba",
    "titulo" : "ToshibaParlante BT Vintage Toshiba",
    "precio" : 109990,
    "fecha_lectura" : ISODate("2019-09-19T23:29:53.555Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d840f71040e9c571c389d20"),
    "marca" : "Toshiba",
    "titulo" : "ToshibaDisco Duro Externo Toshiba Canvio A3 2T",
    "precio" : 69990,
    "fecha_lectura" : ISODate("2019-09-19T23:29:53.560Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Me estoy basando en las dos referencias que tenemos de @Sanz, su snippet y la solución del post de SO en Ingles:

[Duplicados MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489254/mongodb-get-id-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-group-by-query)

Se replicó el problema en *MongoDB Atlas -> Aggregation*, pero use *node.js* para poder acercarme a una solución.

Se hicieron pruebas con *node.js* para este snippet, funciona para crear una nueva colección de Documentos llamada "no_repetidos_ultima_visita".

Esta nueva colección:
        -Descarta los repetidos.
        -Presenta los Docs por fecha mas reciente de visita(fecha_lectura).

```
//mongodb packages from npm
; (async () => {
    try {
        //MongoDB Authentication....
        //set db variable
        await db.collection("nombre_collecion").aggregate([
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$titulo",
                    ultima_fecha_lectura: {
                        "$first": "$$ROOT"
                    },
                    max_fecha_lectura: {
                        "$max": "$fecha_lectura"
                    },
                    duplicados: { "$addToSet": "$_id" },
                    count: { "$sum": 1 }
                }
            },
        ],
            { allowDiskUse: true }
        )
            .forEach(function (doc) {
                duplicatesRecentDateArray.push(doc.ultima_fecha_lectura);
            })

        const insertManyDocs = await db.collection("no_repetidos_ultima_visita").insertMany(duplicatesRecentDateArray);
    } catch (err) {
        console.errors(err.stack);
    }
})()
```

En MongoDB Atlas después de ejecutar el snippet:
[image: Nueva colección después de ejecutar en snippet de node.js]

Si consideras usar el snippet, lo recomendable es:

> Tener una copia de la colección original

.
Claro hay que pasarle los siguientes parámetros en *node.js* de acuerdo a tu configuración:
-db
-nombre_collecion

Saludos

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el enlace a la fuente de donde consultaste, es decir la publicación original de SO en inglés

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Algo prácticamente igual a lo que quieres viene en esta pregunta de SO en inglés:

[máximo valor en un grupo con query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489254/mongodb-get-id-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-group-by-query)

Adaptado a tu conjunto de datos debería ser algo así:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$sort": {
            "fecha_lectura": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$titulo",
            "max_fecha_lectura": {
                "$max": "$fecha_lectura"
            },
        "documento": {
                "$first": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Mira a ver si te sirve porque aunque la salida no es exáctamente igual que la que tu pones, puede que te sirva.